# Is there a promise spec for strongly typed languages?

Tags: javascript, promise, specifications, strong-typing

The [Promises/A+](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) spec is excellent to implement promises, but it uses Javascript's weak typing a lot. Is there a spec for Promises that is designed with languages with strong, static typing such as C#?

Comment: There is no direct analogy in strongly typed languages. However the main goal - flatten code that handles async operations is acheived in this or that manner https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises#List_of_implementations

Comment: What makes you think that promises are weak/strong typing dependent?

Comment: @freakish The fact that from any level in chain you can return a value (which will feed the next handler in chain) or return a promise (which will stick into the chain before next handler). How would you return an arbitrary object OR a promise in a strongly typed language?

Comment: @KirillSlatin You create an abstract base class, say `Result` and you pass around subclasses of it. Dude, that's ABC of static programming.

Comment: @freakish there is an abstract base class in both C# and Java, for example. It is named "Object". And it is a very bad idea to use it, because it throws a lot of type safety checks out the window — just try to use .NET 1.0 non-generic collections, for example.

This is ABC of bad static programming.

Comment: @freakish, no offense, I never thought in this way. So, after your remark I reread the Promise/A+ spec and I agree, one can go from an interface IResult and so. And in this case it would be possible to implement with some limitations. First is that `value` is not _any possible value_ (terminology #3) but IResult implementation. And second, A+ spec is clearly defined for JS with it's one-threaded nature. I can't judge at the moment which implications it will have on implementation in strongly typed lang

Comment: From what I can see, you can just omit the pieces that are specifically for JavaScript (as they are not even needed in strongly typed languages), and it wouldn't be a problem to implement it. The basic principle of a promise isn't very complicated, most of the stuff in the spec is just common good programming practice.

Comment: @MaxYankov Yes, using a class you don't understand is a bad programming. :D But how is that related to what I've written?

Comment: @freakish because what you propose is essentially the same. If the only static compile-time guarantee that you have about something is that it belongs to abstract `Result` class, it is no different from just passing `Object`s around: it throws type safety out of the window.

Comment: @MaxYankov Dude, again: if you don't understand it, don't use it. There is no way to deal with that problem without virtual abstract classes. Just like it is impossible to deal with (for example) JSON without virtual abstract classes. It is by far NOT a bad programming. You have to realize that without this concept there would be NO weakly typed languages to begin with.

Comment: "There is no way to deal with that problem without virtual abstract classes." I find it completely not true. Right now I'm using strongly typed C# promise library that strongly specifies what kind of result each delegate will provide.

Comment: @MaxYankov Oh, sure, you can also create a seperate class for ALL possible results. Yeah, that's better. Oh, but wait, what if I want to return something else? Darn it... So, as you can see that doesn't solve the problem. It only solves a subset of the problem.

Comment: @MaxYankov the way to model "or" between types in a statically typed language is union types - Haskell and TypeScript for example have them - (`Promise<string> | string` is valid TypeScript). C# does not.

Comment: @freakish if you want to return something else, you want to break the data contract — which statically typed languages don't allow you anyway. So, your arguments are arguments against static typing in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of languages have promises, they're a useful and fundamental building block for concurrency. A lot of them have promises built in as part of their base class library.

- C#'s [`Task<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Scala's [`Future[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future)
- Java 8's [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).
- Python's [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future). (Not statically typed though).
- Haskell's [`IO a`](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside).
- clojure's [`promise`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise).
- Dart's [`Future<T>`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.Future).
- C++'s [`std::future<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

Most other languages have dominant implementations in userland, for example Swift's and Objective-C's [Promise](http://promisekit.org/) with PromiseKit.

I can go on and on, but the pattern is really everywhere. Most languages have it specified in their language specification. JavaScript is unique in *how many implementations* there are for promises and the fact the specification tells them *how to interoperate with each other*.

They're not all identical to promises but they all capture the same idea of a future value. Some are much more limited (no monadic chaining) but most are not.

Comment: Note: I assume you're talking about static typing (and not "strong") typing, otherwise you don't want A+ you want https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-promises

Comment: notice that those fantasy-promises are synchronous by design and don't even cache their values (more like `IO a`)

Comment: @Bergi: that fantasy-promise refers to this discussion: https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94 and the slow (in some cases very, very slow) realization by the promise A+ spec authors/community that promises are a monad. Technically, very strongly typed functional (not OO) languages like Haskell use monads instead which is what the semi-joking fantasy-promises tried to imply.

Comment: @slebetman the realization that "promises are monads in their nature" is something that is known since the 80s. People just didn't (some still don't) find that particular realization meaningful or important :) (of course, these were not JS promises)